# Excluding a label from a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first post :)

I am using a Google Apps Script that tracks e-mail from the last 7 days that have not had a response (basically tracks emails where my message is the last one).

This is the code here:

```
// This script searches Gmail for conversations where I never received a response
// and puts them in a NoResponse label 

var DAYS_TO_SEARCH = 7; // look only in sent messages from last 7 days, otherwise script takes a while
var SINGLE_MESSAGE_ONLY = false; // exclude multi-message conversations where I sent the last message? 

function label_messages_without_response() {
  var emailAddress = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(emailAddress);
  var EMAIL_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z\.A-Z]+/g;
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel("AwaitingResponse");
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - DAYS_TO_SEARCH);
  var dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate();
  threads = GmailApp.search("in:Sent after:" + dateString);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    var thread = threads[i];
    if (!SINGLE_MESSAGE_ONLY || thread.getMessageCount() == 1)
    {
      var lastMessage = thread.getMessages()[thread.getMessageCount()-1];
      lastMessageSender = lastMessage.getFrom().match(EMAIL_REGEX)[0];
      if (lastMessageSender == emailAddress)
      {
      thread.addLabel(label);
      Logger.log(lastMessageSender);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is at the moment, when the script runs the un-replied messages go into the "NoResponse" label which is great. However, when I delete the label from the emails that I don't need to follow up on, they come back up again when the script runs again.

My question is:

**Would there would be a way to apply a label to messages that don't need to be followed up on, and then work that into the script, so that the script knows to exclude that label?**

Any help would be fantastic :)

Thanks
Aidan

Comment: Make sure you are familiar with how labels within conversations work as opposed to individual posts. For label based workflows to work well you need to apply/remove labels at the thread level and not message level. A search for the absence if a label for example will include child messages of a thread that does have a label applied. Frustrating but workable if you stay vigilant.

Answer (score 0):

May be the script can apply two labels - NoResponse and Processed. You can remove the NoResponse label manually and yet the Processed label would stay.

The filter can be modified like:

```
 threads = GmailApp.search("in:Sent -in:Processed after:" + dateString);
```

Comment: As per my comment on the OP, be very careful with the way search and labels interact. The API matches the UI at least but there are pitfalls with a label/star based workflow. A not insignificant edge case is always for processed threads then receiving new messages.